# SELECT columns which contain data first

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have result of a query as below first table but the requirement is to display columns first which contain data in it.

Result:

[image: enter code here]

Requirement:

[image]

Sample data generation:

```
Create table #CustData
(
CustID int,
CustName varchar(500),
VL1 varchar(10),
VL2 varchar(10),
VL3 varchar(10),
VL4 varchar(10),
VL5 varchar(10),
VL6 varchar(10),
NUMBER INT
)


INSERT INTO #CustData (CustID,CustName,VL1,VL2,VL3,VL4,VL5,VL6,NUMBER)
SELECT 1,'ABC', NULL, 'dl2','dl3','dl4','dl5','dl6',08586
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'DEF', 'dl1', 'dl2',NULL,'dl4','dl5','dl6',54646
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'GHI', 'dl1', 'dl2','','dl4',NULL,'dl6',6464
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'JKL', NULL, 'dl2','dl3','dl4','dl5',NULL,44645
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'MNO', 'dl1', NULL,NULL,'dl4','dl5','dl6',46457256
```

Comment: Can you please convert the "Result" and "Requirement" images into text as well please?

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) might be of interest - it's why screenshots are discouraged here!

Answer (score 2):

You could `UNPIVOT`, apply a `ROW_NUMBER` and then `PIVOT` it back.

```
select
    CustID, 
    CustName, 
    [1] as [VL1], 
    [2] as [VL2], 
    [3] as [VL3], 
    [4] as [VL4], 
    [5] as [VL5], 
    [6] as [VL6],
    NUMBER
from(
    select 
        CustID, 
        CustName, 
        NUMBER, 
        V, 
        Seq = row_number() over (partition by CustID order by case when V = '' then 7 else null end)
    from
        (
        select 
            CustID, 
            CustName, 
            VL1, 
            VL2, 
            VL3, 
            VL4, 
            VL5, 
            VL6, 
            NUMBER
        from #CustData
        ) as cp
    unpivot
        (
        V for Vs in (VL1, VL2, VL3, VL4, VL5, VL6)
        ) up
    ) s
pivot
    (
    Max(V) for Seq in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
    ) p
```